# Kernel of linear map $f:L_{3}\rightarrow L_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I need to find the kernel of the next linear map, first let $A$ be a local ring with residue field of size $2$.  Then I have the next row vectors $0:=(0,1)$, $\infty:= (1,0)$ and $x_{+}:=(x,1)$

Therefore I consider the next modules:

$L_{3}$ is the free  $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by the elements of the forms  $(\infty,0,x_{+})$, $(\infty,x_{+},0)$, $(0,x_{+},\infty)$, $(0,\infty,x_{+})$  , $(x_{+},0,\infty)$ and $(x_{+},\infty,0)$ where $x$ a unit in $A$.

$L_{2}$ is the free  $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by the elements of the forms  $(\infty,0)$, $(\infty,x_{+})$, $(0,x_{+})$, $(0,\infty)$  , $(x_{+},0)$ and $(x_{+},\infty)$ where $x$ a unit in $A$

Now I consider the next linear map of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules

$f:L_{3}\rightarrow L_{2}$

given by

$(x,y,z)\mapsto(y,z)-(x,z)+(x,y)$

I found that the elements $(z,y,x)+(y,z,x)-(x,y,z)-(x,z,y)$ are in the kernel of $f$. I would like to know if there are more elements in the kernel. That's why I am trying to find the kernel of the map $f$.

One idea is similar of the case of the field  of two elements $\mathbb{F}_{2}$, the matriz that represent the map $f$ is given by the following matrix

$\beta=\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1& -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
    -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
$

For the case of I am interested I did the same idea to see if I can get something and  I have and infinite matrix where the diagonal are blocks formed by the matrix $\beta$

$\left(
  \begin{array}{ccccc}
    \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    \cdots & \beta & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
    \cdots & 0 & \beta &0& \cdots \\
    \cdots & 0 & 0 & \beta & \cdots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
  \end{array}
\right)$

I am not sure if there is such thing of a null space for infinite matrices so I would appreciate any suggestion or hint about finding the kernel of that map.